# Writing chef rspec test using 'execute'

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

In my .rb file, I am attempting to write a spec test against this line of code (I did not write this code):

```
execute "lvcreate -L #{node['ami_base']['opt']} -n opt vgpool"
```

In my _spec.rb file, my test looks like this for this particular section of code:

```
it 'executes lvcreate... -n opt vgpool' do
  expect(chef_run).to run_execute("lvcreate -L #{node['ami_base']['opt']} -n opt vgpool")
end
```

When I attempt:

```
chef exec rspec....._spec.rb
```

I receive this error:

```
1) ami_base::lvm_drives executes lvcreate... -n opt vgpool
 Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to run_execute("lvcreate -L #{node['ami_base']['opt']} -n opt vgpool")

 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `node' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AmiBaseLvmDrives:0x0000000005752268>
 # ./spec/unit/recipes/lvm_drives_spec.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've written many tests against `execute` and they've all been successful. Do I need to modify the spec helper file? I feel like it being a command line input and creating a volume that the command should be something other than run_execute, but i am coming up empty handed in a my searches for anything that works.

Comment: Please, post the text of the error message as text, not as a photograph of text. This is a programming site, not a photography site. We want to read, copy, and paste the error, not critique its use of color and perspective. (Although if I may offer a critique nonetheless: the dark red on black is completely unreadable on my screen.)

Comment: Will do. First post on the site,  so I'm learning how it works. I'll get the text up

Comment: error message text has been added.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t use node attributes in your spec like that, the point of the test is to manually expand it to make sure your code worked.